Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm' for 'net8.0' in Blazor project
Claro, aqui está como você pode formular sua pergunta no Stack Overflow em inglês:

Title: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm' for 'net8.0' in Blazor project
Body:
Hello everyone,
I'm working on a Blazor project and I encountered an issue when trying to restore NuGet packages. Here is the error message I'm getting:
Severity    Code    Description    Project    File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)    NU1100    Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm (= 8.0.6)' for 'net8.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org.    Imc    C:\MyBlazorApps\IMC\src\Imc.csproj    1    

I've checked the following:

Package source settings in Visual Studio
Internet connection
Version compatibility

Here's the relevant part of my .csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm" Version="8.0.6" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
I checked my package sources in Visual Studio to ensure they include nuget.org, verified my internet connection, and confirmed the version compatibility of the package. I expected the package to be resolved and restored without any issues. However, the error persists and the package cannot be resolved.

I managed to resolve the issue by removing the NuGet packages and then adding them again. Here are the steps I followed:

Remove the problematic package:

Open the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio.
Locate the Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm package.
Uninstall the package.


Clear the NuGet cache:

Open the command prompt.
Run the following command to clear the NuGet cache:
nuget locals all -clear




Re-add the package:

Go back to the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio.
Search for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm.
Install the package again.


Restore the NuGet packages:

Right-click on the solution in Visual Studio.
Select Restore NuGet Packages.



After following these steps, the package was successfully resolved and restored. I hope this helps anyone facing a similar issue!

I used dotnet add package command to install this package but can't install too. From looking at the README from nuget org,it notes:

Internal implementation package not meant for direct consumption. Please do not reference directly.

This doc notes FrameworkReference ,
to reference ASP.NET Core, try to add the following  element to your project file:
 <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />

Hope it can help you.

Thanks for helping, but the problem there is only resolved after cleaning the nuget references, I don't know why it gets lost like this.
